# What's happening when Ruby shows something like this: #<Role:0x11157b630>?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I remember coming across this when first watching some Ruby videos, but I can't find it again. When Ruby shows something like this:

```
#<Role:0x11157b630>
```

,what is going on?

I have three roles (admin/staff/client) and I would like to show one of these, not

```
#<Role:0x11157b630>.
```

Any idea how I could do that?

Cheers!

Comment: What is the column name in the Role model?  What does the line of code that outputs this message look like?

Comment: The table 'roles' has the fields 'id' and 'name'. The code that outputs this is <td><%=h user.roles %></td>. In user.rb, I have def role
    roles.first
  end

  def role=(role_id)
    self.roles = [Role.find(role_id)]
  end

Answer (score 5):

What you're seeing is just a representation of the instance you've got. Say you have a `title` attribute on the class `Role`, you could, instead of `logger.debug @role` do something like `logger.debug @role.title`. If you want just doing `logger.debug @role` to print out something more useful, define a `to_s` method on `Role`.

Answer (score 2):

Appending an inspect method should show some more details.

```
@role.inspect
```

Comment: Thanks! With inspect I get [#<Role id: 1, name: "admin">] and [#<Role id: 2, name: "staff">] and [#<Role id: 3, name: "client">]. When I do something like user.roles.name I get "Role".

Comment: Hey, you can't do user.roles.name because user.roles probably returns an array. Try user.roles.first.name  or if you want all of them then use user.roles.collect(&:name).

Answer (score 1):

That's what the default implementation of `to_s` looks like; class name followed by memory location. You can define your own version if you like:

```
def to_s
   "My name is #{@name}"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

When I started with rails I had strange bugs sometimes when I made something simple like:

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
  ....
<% end %>
```

I would get those strange outputs under the list of posts.

For example:

```
#<Post:0x11157b630>#<Post:0x11157b630>#<Post:0x11157b630>
```

Turns out I accidentally put a "=" in there before the loop.

```
<%= @posts.each do |post| %>
      ....
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [The Secret of Object#to_s](http://solutious.com/blog/2009/09/22/secret-of-object-to_s/), the number in `#<Role:0x11157b630>` is double the object's `object_id` in hexidecimal.